# What causes "flushing %s elements"?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm experimenting with custom polymer elements in Dart using the Dart Editor. I haven't been able to figure out why, but I often get this printed in the output:

```
flushing %s elements (http://localhost:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)
```

My elements show up for a brief second after launching the app but then disappear whenever this message is displayed. What is causing this? The only thing I was able to find online was [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20564).

EDIT: I just realized that the fact that my elements are not being displayed might not be related to this message, but I would still like to know what it means.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the message. As far as I remember the message is printed every time I launch a Polymer application.  I have never seen any comment related to this message beside the issue you linked to.

Comment: Ok, probably something else then. I'm having a hard time figuring out what is wrong when using Dart. Hopefully it will get better soon.